# Fixed-sized Android webView cutting off a fixed-sized image which should fit exactly

Tags: android, html, webview

I have two webViews stacked on top of each other. In the bottom webView, webViewB, I am displaying a simple HTML page with a viewport size of 321x60 and an image of the same dimensions. Initially I set the webViewB height to 60, but that was too small and caused the image to get cut off. So then I set the webViewB height to be 60 * density:

```
int scaledBottomHeight = (int)(60 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams bottomLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, scaledBottomHeight);
webViewB.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);    // So viewport meta tag will work
webViewB.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webViewB.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
webViewB.setLayoutParams(bottomLayoutParams);
```

On a Galaxy S2 with a density of 1.5 (making the height 90) this works perfect. Every part of the image is seen without any cutoff or extra space. On a Galaxy S4 with a density of 3.0 (making the height 180) the image is still getting cut off. I had to increase webViewB's height by an additional 20 pixels before it looked correct.

If I change setUseWideViewPort to false then the image height is displayed correctly but width is too narrow, having empty space on either side. This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=321, height=60, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=false"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
    <div style="height:60px;"><img src="img-963x180.png" width="321" height="60" alt=""/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on why my image is getting cut off in webViewB and what I can do to correct it?

Comment: Could it have something to do with the different aspect ratio? Galaxy S2 is 3:5 while the S4 is 9:16.